# In Ionic, is it possible to publish ios inhouse?

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, in-house-distribution

I'm piloting ionic,
is it possible to publish ios inhouse?

```
if (is possible)
{
     would you give me a guide?
}
```

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

both apps

1. which you developed using ionic-framework
2. ios native app created using objc/swift

will give `.ipa` file.you have to use this to distribute your app.

distributing ios app inhouse is related to your developer account.It has nothing to do with ionic-framework.

check these [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/DistributingEnterpriseProgramApps/DistributingEnterpriseProgramApps.html)